ESP32 does not receive ping responses
the USB on my ESP32 WROOM when connected to an external power source does not respond to ping requests, but when it is connected directly to the notebook, ping occurs and it shows the responses on the serial monitor. What could it be?
I checked if there was any serial.println in the code that ping could be dependent on and there isn't.

Hi Kethely, welcome to SO. Currently it's hard to understand what you're asking. Please elaborate on what exactly you've done, what is your setup, what are the expected and actual results.

Ping is well-known technique for TCP/IP networks, but not for USB and/or serial connection. Please elaborate what kind of ping you are using. What kind of connections to and from the ESP32 do you have in the two setups? How is the external power source connected?
